# Java Pattern Matcher evaluating regex incorrectly

Tags: java, regex

I'm searching for a quote followed by four digits a quote and a colon in a given string - which should be the regex ("\d{4}":) if I have my stuff straight. However, the following my code:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\"[0-9]{4}\":)");
System.out.println("Regex: " + regex.pattern());
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(itemJson);
String itemId;
String toReplace;
String replaceWith;
int lastIndex;
while(matcher.find()){
    lastIndex = matcher.start(); 
    itemId = itemJson.substring(lastIndex+1, lastIndex+5);
    toReplace = itemJson.substring(lastIndex, lastIndex+8);
    replaceWith = "{ \"id\":" + itemId + ",";
    System.out.println(itemJson.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
    itemJson = itemJson.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
}
```

Prints out the following:

```
Regex: "[0-9]{4}":
"1001":
0}},"10
":0.6}}
nMod":1
```

I have no idea what is going wrong honestly... I'm using Eclipse Kepler with Java SE 1.6 in case that matters.

EDIT: itemJson is a string being passed to this class that is taken from a server. For the output above, I was using an abbreviated version:

```
"data":{"1001":{"name":"Boots of Speed","plaintext":"Slightly increases Movement Speed","group":"BootsNormal","description":"<groupLimit>Limited to 1.</groupLimit><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Enhanced Movement:</unique> +25 Movement Speed<br><br><i>(Unique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>","colloq":";","into":["3006","3047","3020","3158","3111","3117","3009"],"image":{"full":"1001.png","sprite":"item0.png","group":"item","x":0,"y":0,"w":48,"h":48},"gold":{"base":325,"total":325,"sell":227,"purchasable":true},"tags":["Movement","Boots"],"stats":{"FlatMovementSpeedMod":25.0}},"1004":{"name":"Faerie Charm","plaintext":"Slightly increases Mana Regen","description":"<stats>+3 Mana Regen per 5 seconds</stats>","colloq":";","into":["3152","3028","3070","3073","1080","3069","3165"],"image":{"full":"1004.png","sprite":"item0.png","group":"item","x":48,"y":0,"w":48,"h":48},"gold":{"base":180,"total":180,"sell":126,"purchasable":true},"tags":["ManaRegen"],"stats":{"FlatMPRegenMod":0.6}},"1006":{"name":"Rejuvenation Bead","plaintext":"Slightly increases Health Regen","description":"<stats>+5 Health Regen per 5 seconds</stats>","colloq":";","into":["3077","3097","3112","3083","1080","2051","3105"],"image":{"full":"1006.png","sprite":"item0.png","group":"item","x":96,"y":0,"w":48,"h":48},"gold":{"base":180,"total":180,"sell":126,"purchasable":true},"tags":["HealthRegen"],"stats":{"FlatHPRegenMod":1.0}},"1011":{"name":"Giant's Belt","plaintext":"Greatly increases Health","description":"<stats>+380 Health</stats>","colloq":";","into":["3083","3022","3068","3116","3084","3143"],"image":{"full":"1011.png","sprite":"item0.png","group":"item","x":144,"y":0,"w":48,"h":48},"gold":{"base":1000,"total":1000,"sell":700,"purchasable":true},"tags":["Health"],"stats":{"FlatHPPoolMod":380.0}}}
```

Thanks @aliteralmind

Comment: Show the input string

Comment: Yes `(\d{4}:)` should work.  try on http://regexpal.com/ - why not just use a String.replace?

Comment: Are you sure that pattern matcher is evaluating wrong? Could it instead be that your understanding of it be off? Just a thought.

Comment: If you're trying to match 7 characters, why are you're increasing `lastIndex` by 8? A few input strings really would help out here.

Comment: @user2310289 I'm not using replace because I wasn't aware that it could do what I wanted - I'm trying to rearrange a JSON I have to form a group of objects, taking the object name and moving it inside the object and placing it under the "id" field.

Comment: Why use REGEX? Why not use a dedicated JSON parser?

Comment: @aliteralmind I've added a sample input string, sorry!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well that would be the preferred explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not resetting the matcher at the end of each while iteration. Fix:

```
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
   <P>{@code java RegexTest}</P>
 **/
public class RegexTest  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
        String itemJson = "{\"data\":{{ \"id\":1001,\"name\":\"Boots of Speed\",\"plaintext\":\"Slightly increases Movement Speed\",\"group\":\"BootsNormal\",\"description\":\"<groupLimit>Limited to 1.</groupLimit><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Enhanced Movement:</unique> +25 Movement Speed<br><br><i>(Unique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>\",\"colloq\":\";\",\"into\":[\"3006\",\"3047\",\"3020\",\"3158\",\"3111\",\"3117\",\"3009\"],\"image\":{\"full\":\"1001.png\",\"sprite\":\"item0.png\",\"group\":\"item\",\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"w\":48,\"h\":48},\"gold\":{\"base\":325,\"total\":325,\"sell\":227,\"purchasable\":true},\"tags\":[\"Movement\",\"Boots\"],\"stats\":{\"FlatMovementSpeedMod\":25.{ \"id\":}},\",4\":{\"name\":\"Faerie Charm\",\"plaintext\":\"Slightly increases Mana Regen\",\"description\":\"<stats>+3 Mana Regen per 5 seconds</stats>\",\"colloq\":\";\",\"into\":[\"3152\",\"3028\",\"3070\",\"3073\",\"1080\",\"3069\",\"3165\"],\"image\":{\"full\":\"1004.png\",\"sprite\":\"item0.png\",\"group\":\"item\",\"x\":48,\"y\":0,\"w\":48,\"h\":48},\"gold\":{\"base\":180,\"total\":180,\"sell\":126,\"purchasable\":true},\"tags\":[\"ManaRegen\"],\"stats\":{\"FlatMPRegenMod{ \"id\"::0.6,\"1006\":{\"name\":\"Rejuvenation Bead\",\"plaintext\":\"Slightly increases Health Regen\",\"description\":\"<stats>+5 Health Regen per 5 seconds</stats>\",\"colloq\":\";\",\"into\":[\"3077\",\"3097\",\"3112\",\"3083\",\"1080\",\"2051\",\"3105\"],\"image\":{\"full\":\"1006.png\",\"sprite\":\"item0.png\",\"group\":\"item\",\"x\":96,\"y\":0,\"w\":48,\"h\":48},\"gold\":{\"base\":180,\"total\":180,\"sell\":126,\"purchasable\":true},\"tags\":[\"HealthRegen\"],\"stats\":{\"FlatHPRege{ \"id\":Mod\",0}},\"1011\":{\"name\":\"Giant's Belt\",\"plaintext\":\"Greatly increases Health\",\"description\":\"<stats>+380 Health</stats>\",\"colloq\":\";\",\"into\":[\"3083\",\"3022\",\"3068\",\"3116\",\"3084\",\"3143\"],\"image\":{\"full\":\"1011.png\",\"sprite\":\"item0.png\",\"group\":\"item\",\"x\":144,\"y\":0,\"w\":48,\"h\":48},\"gold\":{\"base\":1000,\"total\":1000,\"sell\":700,\"purchasable\":true},\"tags\":[\"Health\"],\"stats\":{\"FlatHPPoolMod\":380.0}}}";

      Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\"[0-9]{4}\":)");
      System.out.println("Regex: " + regex.pattern());
      Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(itemJson);
      String itemId;
      String toReplace;
      String replaceWith;
      int lastIndex;
      while(matcher.find()){
         lastIndex = matcher.start();
         itemId = itemJson.substring(lastIndex+1, lastIndex+5);
System.out.println("-itemId=\"" + itemId + "\"");
         toReplace = itemJson.substring(lastIndex, lastIndex+8);
System.out.println("-toReplace=\"" + toReplace + "\"");
         replaceWith = "{ \"id\":" + itemId + ",";
System.out.println("-replaceWith=\"" + replaceWith + "\"");
         System.out.println(itemJson.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
         itemJson = itemJson.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);

         //Must reset the matcher for the updated string!
         matcher.reset(itemJson);
      }
   }
}
```

Output (debugging indented):

```
[C:\java_code\]java RegexTest
Regex: ("[0-9]{4}":)
      -itemId="1006"
      -toReplace=""1006":{"
      -replaceWith="{ "id":1006,"
"1006":
      -itemId="1011"
      -toReplace=""1011":{"
      -replaceWith="{ "id":1011,"
"1011":
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! I knew I was missing something stupid